# innerHTML changes my characters in my string

Tags: javascript

When I try to change a paragraph using the innerHTML, it changes some characters. Look at the code:

```
texto.innerHTML = "Durante as últimas 2 semanas, com que freqüência você foi incomodado/a por qualquer um dos problemas abaixo?";
```

The output is this:
Durante as �ltimas 2 semanas, com que freq��ncia voc� foi incomodado/a por qualquer um dos problemas abaixo?

insted of this:
Durante as últimas 2 semanas, com que freqüência você foi incomodado/a por qualquer um dos problemas abaixo? novo

What are those question marks?

Comment: What encoding type have you specified for your HTML?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a different encoding in js files and browser output.
Try to change the javascript file encoding to the UTF8 without the BOM.

Comment: Yes. I think it could be this. But, how can I change the javascript file to the UTF8 without the Bom?

Comment: thanks. I've created a new javascript document, past the old code into it and it worked well. But I still want to know how to change the enconding to UTF8.

Comment: Depend on used IDE/Text editor. In IDE try to check the new document settings.
For Notepad++ (text editor) you can use special menu "Encoding->Conver to UTF8 without BOM".

Answer (score 1):

This is due to an encoding issue. Rather than using accented characters, you need to use the HTML special characters.

For example:

`ü` should be

```
&#252;
```

See a full list here

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp